# Echo Effect: Write audio buffers with offset?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-audio

Is it possible to write the audio buffers with an offset(delay) to generate a flat echo effect ?

The following piece of code outputs my audio buffers :

```
for(s=0; s<inNumberFrames; s++) {
    ioBuffer[s] = audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
}
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this within the **for loop** :

```
tempBuffer[s] = audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
--- Then somehow offset tempBuffer[] as bufferWithOffset[] --- 
ioBuffer[s] = audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos] + bufferWithOffset[];
```

Any guidance in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work, thanks to Hollance on RW Forums for explaining all of this to me.

[ http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2864 ]

I still have a lot of crashing issues, caused most probably by memory leaks. But the logic works.

---

Initialized a temporary buffer with 22050 zero samples :

```
(SInt16 *)tempBuffer = (SInt16*)calloc(22050, sizeof(SInt16));
```

Initialized a long counter with zero :

```
long d=0;
```

Then within the **for loop** fed the temporary buffer mixed with the current sample :

```
for(s=0; s<inNumberFrames; s++) {
    ioBuffer[s] = tempBuffer[d] + audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
```

Added the current sample to the tempBuffer :

```
    tempBuffer[d] = audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
    d++;
```

Reset the counter to zero if the limit of the tempBuffer is reached :

```
    if(d >= 22050)
    d=0;
}
```

Assuming that the sampling rate is 44100 Hz, this will create a delay of 0.5 seconds.

---

**UPDATE :**

Changed

```
    ioBuffer[s] = tempBuffer[d] + audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
```

To

```
    ioBuffer[s] = 0.6*tempBuffer[d] + 0.4*audioBuffer[audioBufferReadPos];
```

And that fixed the crashing.

Comment: Hi,
May you provide me this code. as I am new on objective c and don't know how to create audioBuffer from audio file.